# Implementing findOrCreate strategy with spring data in concurrent environment

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm facing the following problem:

I have an entity:

```
        @Table(name = "host",
                uniqueConstraints = 
    { 
@UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_host_0", 
        columnNames = {"orgName", "hostName"})}
)
class Host {

   private String id;

   private String hostName;
   private String orgName;

   //gets
   //sets
   //constructors
   //...

}
```

This entity has uniqueness constrain on **orgName** + **hostName** fields.

And corresponding Repository for the entity:

```
public interface HostRepository extends JpaRepository<Host, String> {

    Page<Host> findByOrgId(String orgId, Pageable pageable);

    Host findOneByOrgNameIdAndId(String orgName, String id);

    Host findOneByOrgNameAndHostName(String orgName, String hostName);

   //..
}
```

I want to create a service with findOrCreate method that would:

1. Create new Host in case if Host does not exist
2. If Host does exist, return the Host

Taking into account uniqueness constraint on **hostName + orgName** fields.

This method should work in assumption that it can be executed on multiple different instances of the same application as well as in different threads.

Currently I came up with two solutions:

1. Use separate method for creation with Propagation = RequiresNew

   ```
   @Service
    public class HostService {

      @Autowired
      private HostRepository hostRepository;

       @Transactional
       public Host findOrCreate(Host host) {

          try {

           return create(host);

         } catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
           //means the host has already been created by other transaction
            return hostRepository.findFirstByOrgNameAndHostName(host.getHostName(), host.getOrgName());
         }

       }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Host create(Host host) {
        //constraint violation may be thrown
         hostRepository.save(host);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Perform all the logic in one method, but with isolation level = serializable:

   ```
   @Service
   public class HostService {

    @Autowired
    private HostRepository hostRepository;

   @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
   public Host findOrCreate(Host host) {

      Optional<Host> existing = Optional.ofNullable(hostRepository.findOneByOrgNameAndHostName(host.getOrgName(), host.getHostName()));

      if(existing.isPresent()) {
         return existing;
      }

      return hostRepository.save(host);
   }
   ```

   }

It seems to me that both of these options would work in concurrent environment and the first option is preferable because works faster. However, I'm afraid that I may miss underwater rocks.

Did anyone face the problem before?

If so, I would really grateful for any advice or alternative solutions apart from listed above,

Thanks, cheers

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in some DBs locks won't be taken over nonexistent indexes even in serializable txs, so first solution is the only viable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea.
You can define one method in HostRepository like:

```
Optional<Host> findByOrgNameAndHostName(String orgName, String hostName)
```

And in HostService, you can use the method:

```
Host host = hostRepository.findByOrgNameAndHostName("hoge", "fuga")
               .orElseGet(() -> hostRepository.save(new Host("hoge", "fuga")))
```

Comment: This works but it is still not thread safe. If another process or thread inserts the new `Host("hoge","fuga")` after the `findByOrgNameAndHostName` has finished but before the `save` takes place, you will get a duplicate key exception or duplicate rows.